# Why set.seed() affects sample() in R

Tags: r, random, sampling, resampling

I always thought `set.seed()` only makes random variable generators (e.g., `rnorm`) to generate a unique sequence for any specific set of input values.

However, I'm wondering, why when we set the `set.seed()`, then the function `sample()` doesn't do its job correctly?

### Question

**Specifically, given the below example,** is there a way I can use `set.seed` before the `rnorm` but `sample` would still produce new random samples from this `rnorm` if `sample` is run multiple times?

## Here is an R code:

```
set.seed(123458)
x.y = rnorm(1e2)

sampled = sample(x = x.y, size = 20, replace = TRUE)

plot(sampled)
```

Comment: What do you think `sample()` does?

Comment: `set.seed` has an effect on all random number draws. `sample` uses random number draws.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the help file at `?set.seed`

> "If called with seed = NULL it re-initializes (see ‘Note’) as if no
>   seed had yet been set."

So, since `rnorm` and `sample` are both affected by `set.seed()`, you can do:

```
set.seed(639245)
rn <- rnorm(1e2)
set.seed(NULL)
sample(rn,5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of resetting the seed with `NULL`, I think it makes more sense to save the current state and restore it.

```
x <- .Random.seed
set.seed(639245)
rn <- rnorm(1e2)
.Random.seed <- x
sample(rn,5)
```